# Find Free Prefixes within a CIDR netblock

Tags: java, networking, routes, cidr

I'm trying to figure out a way to determine "free prefixes" within a CIDR netblock given the netblock and a list of assignments from within it.

For example:

let netblock = 10.0.0.0/22

let assignments = { 10.0.0.0/24, 10.0.1.0/24 }

What would be the most computationally efficient way of figuring out the "free" netblocks from within 10.0.0.0/22? I need to output 10.0.2.0/23 for the above example.

I've tried researching and have mostly come up empty. The only way that comes to my mind (probably due to my inexperience with network programming) is:

1. CIDR -> list of IPs expansion
2. Match on the common IPs and remove them from the list
3. Convert the modified list back to the CIDR notation.

This however sounds fairly inefficient (I would call it the "bruteforce" approach).

I'm fine with a general algorithm, it doesn't have to be a Java specific answer.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Your example is a "perfect case", as your assignments are allocated at the beginning of the parent block, and are aligned by the bit boundary nicely, but you might as well have something like "10.0.2.111/30" in the list, in which case you won't be able to define a single continuous block to cover 10.0.0.0-10.0.2.110 and will have to define N output blocks to cover the range 10.0.0.0-10.0.2.107 plus M output blocks to cover 10.0.2.112-10.0.3.255. That still can be done, but is a harder task (at least if you want to find an optimal solution, keeping N and M as small as possible).

Comment: @zeppelin indeed. Well, in my case, the assignment size is guaranteed to always at least be a /24, but I understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an address x/y,  when you subtract it from a set of addresses, what you have left is the addresses in the set a/y, where a < x, and the addresses in the set b/y, where b > x

So in your example, that leaves 10.0.1-3.0/24 when you subtract 10.0.0.0/24 from 10.0.0.0/22.

There are no addresses x/24 in 10.0.0.0/22 where x < 10.0.0.0.  The addresses y/24 in 10.0.0.0/22 where y > 10.0.0.0 are 10.0.1.0/24, 10.0.2.0/24, and  10.0.3.0/24, or 10.0.1-3.0/24.

Another way to look at it: you are removing all addresses whose first 24 bits are 10.0.0

So that leaves all addresses whose first 24 bits are bigger, and all addresses whose first 24 bits are smaller.  Each of those can be expressed as a range.

Just repeat this process iteratively.

Comment: Each of those can be expressed as a range. that is not always the case, e.g. if your source block is 10.0.0.0/21, and you remove 10.0.5.0/24 from it, what is left (on the low side) is 10.0.0.0-1.0.4.255 which can not be written down as a single range in CIDR notation.